# DataInputStream.available() with BluetoothSocket blocking execution on Android 4.2 but not on 4.4

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

Should this available() function be used th check whether is it any data in stream and could it block execution at some circumstances? I'm using this fragment of code (*device* is available and paired):

```
socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
socket.connect();
InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream dataInStream = new DataInputStream(inStream);
if(dataInStream.available()) {
  Log.i("","available");
}
```

Connection is usually successful (i have bluetooth module where led diode that indicates active rfcomm connection). The available() function works as i expect on phone with android 4.4, but on Android 4.2 it just blocks (for example i set breakpoint on line with available() and the next line, and program doesn't pass to the next line). It returns when i turn off bluetooth in phone or unpair device.